# Close Top Activity from Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I followed this tutorial in order to detect network changes and alert the user if there is no network connection:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

I modified the code so that it opens up an activity called NoInternetConnection when the user disconnects from a network.

When the user reconnects to the network, I want to close the NoInternetConnection activity.  I haven't been able to figure this out with the Broadcast Receiver.  Any tips on how to do this?

Here is my Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = NetworkChangeReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "status: " + status);

        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
                getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

        if(status == "connected"){
            if(className.toLowerCase().contains("nointernetactivity")){
                // check if the No Internet Activity context is visible
                Log.d(TAG, "Close noInternetActivity");

            }

        }else {
            if(!className.toLowerCase().contains("nointernetactivity")){
                Log.d(TAG, "opening NoInternetActivity");
                Intent i = new Intent(context, NoInternetActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
            }
        }
//        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my NoInternetActivity, I created a Broadcast Receiver to close the activity:

```
public class NoInternetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Context context;
    private BroadcastReceiver _closeActivityReceiver = new CloseActivityReceiver();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_no_internet);
        context = this;

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("closeNoInternetActivity");
        this.registerReceiver(_closeActivityReceiver, filter);

    }

    private class CloseActivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // close this damn activity!
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        this.unregisterReceiver(this._closeActivityReceiver);
    }

}
```

Then I call it in my Broadcast Receiver like this:

```
        if(className.toLowerCase().contains("nointernetactivity")){
            // check if the No Internet Activity context is visible
            Log.d(TAG, "Close noInternetActivity");
            Intent in = new Intent("closeNoInternetActivity");
            context.sendBroadcast(in);

        }
```

Comment: You might consider using `LocalBroadcastManager` for this. Same pattern as standard broadcasts and `BroadcastReceiver`s - i.e., you'd just need to kinda drop it in - but the broadcasts stay within your app, and are generally faster, noticeably.

Comment: My understanding is that making 'context' static is frowned upon. Android Studio will complain. It is, however, the key to this working.